# What is the meaning of the \\+ in this regex?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to parse this example regex.

I know that slashes can be used as escape characters. So if you wanted to search for ) without implying a grouping you would do `\` and then `)` *spelling this out to avoid stack overflow regex...*

I also know that a plus sign can indicate one or more of the preceding item.

But in the example below, is the plus sign or the slash getting escaped? It seems like the first slash allows you to "escape" the second slash and then the plus sign indicates that there is at least one prior slashes --- but the example says there are at least two + in the string...

What does this regex mean? There are too many new things going on for me to parse it.

[image]

Comment: I've added the [tag:postgresql] tag, as the regex looks like it might be. You can change the tags if it's wrong.

Comment: Your PostgreSQL version is important here, as is the value of the `standard_conforming_strings` parameter. That might be a weirdly phrased regular expression to find anything starting with two or more \s (`standard_conforming_strings=on`) or starting with `++` (`standard_conforming_strings=off`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But in the example below, is the plus sign or the slash getting escaped?

Both!

The `\` is escaped because the query language you are using probably uses it as an escape character itself (i.e. to escape quotes). So `\\` is understood as a single `\` in the regex, which is then used to escape the `+`. The regex means a single `+` followed by zero or many `+`.

It could probably be rewritten as `\\++` where the second `+` is actually the regex quantifier.

Comment: Documentation (assuming postgres): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ESCAPE-SEQUENCES

Comment: Ah there you go, I didn't recognize the SQL flavor.

Comment: @cbuckley what does Vache mean by 'escape quotes'

Comment: @akh2103 If you want to use a string with quotes in it in your query, you could escape them like this `'String with \'quotes\''`

Comment: @akh2103 `'Here\'s an example'` — the \ is being used to escape the quote so that it doesn't close the string literal.

Comment: @Vache I understand your comment. 'use \'slashes \'to include quotes'. But this example does not seem to be including quote marks. Is the idea that the first of these slashes is a postgres escape character that allows you to include the second \ in the query? (Just like you would use \' to include a ' in the query).

Comment: @akh2103 Exactly. By using \\ you are telling PostgreSQL that you are not using \ to escape, but that you actually meant \. Then, the regex engine uses it to escape the `+`.

Comment: @akh2103 have a look at the linked documentation: The first backslash escapes the second one in the string literal. Note that `'\+' == '+'` as string literals, so a single escape character would never be seen by the regex.

Answer (score 2):

That regexp can actually mean two different things, depending on the PostgreSQL version and the value of `standard_conforming_strings`.

Old versions (before `standard_conforming_strings` or those that defaulted to off) would interpret the string as a backslash-escaped string. So PostgreSQL would turn `\\+\\+*` into `\+\+*`, i.e. it'd consume a level of escaping. Then the regular expression would consume the remaining level to escape the pluses, so they're interpreted as literal +s not qualifiers. That regexp says *++ followed by zero or more other characters*.

Newer versions with `standard_conforming_strings` defaulting to `on` will, per the SQL standard, not decode the backslashes as escapes. So you'll run the regexp `\\+\\+*`, which is *one or more backslashes, followed by one or more backslashes, followed by ... oops, the asterisk without a preceding character is an error*.

So we know you must have `standard_conforming_strings` off, 'cos the query would fail to compile the regexp on a new one.

```
regress=> SELECT 'blah' ~ '\\+\\+*';
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

postgres=> SHOW standard_conforming_strings;
 standard_conforming_strings 
-----------------------------
 on
(1 row)
```

You'll have this problem later on, so I suggest dealing with it before you upgrade.

Assuming that the `x_spam_level` field always starts with the pluses, which the regexp doesn't check, that code might be better written as:

```
x_spam_level LIKE '++%'
```

If it doesn't start with the pluses use:

```
x_spam_level LIKE '%++%'
```

which is what the current regexp is doing. PostgreSQL will turn that into a regular expression internally, but you don't have to worry about the escaping.

If you want to use a regular expression and have it behave consisently across all versions, use:

```
x_spam_level ~ E'\\+\\+*'
```

The `E''` syntax tells PostgreSQL to decode backslash escapes, irrespective of the `standard_conforming_strings` setting.